# NetworkOnMainThreadException when trying to abort

Tags: android

I have an AsyncTask that pops up a dialog while it fetches data from a URL and a handler to cancel the request if the dialog is dismissed. It works fine most of the time but I found that it crashes with a NetworkOnMainThreadException once in awhile. My theory is that if the dialog is dismissed after doInBackground() completes but before or while onPostExecute() runs the CancelListener runs on the main thread. So does that theory make sense and how would I handle it properly? Try and Catch?

Here's a sample code:

```
public class TestTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    public ProgressDialog dialog;
    public Context context;
    public HttpUriRequest request;

    public TestTask(Activity activity)
    {
        context = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled()
    {
        if (dialog != null)
            dialog.dismiss();
        super.onCancelled();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        OnCancelListener cancelListener = new OnCancelListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                if (request != null)
                    request.abort(); // this causes NetworkOnMainThreadException sometimes
                TestTask.this.cancel(true);
            }
        };

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(context, "", "Loading", true, true, cancelListener);
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        String url = "some url";
        request = new HttpGet(url);
        // process request
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        dialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

}
```

Comment: Is the `request.abort()` necessary? I thought `cancel(true)` would abort the thread.

Comment: According to the documentations, cancel(true) tells the task to trigger onCancelled() instead of onPostExecute() so whatever happens in doInBackground() will complete so the request won't get aborted. They do suggest putting a loop in doInBackground() to check for isCancelled() but that seems weird to me when it makes more sense to abort on cancel.

Comment: It is, if you pass false. Howerver, checking the code for `FutureTask`, it calls `thread.interrupt()` if `mayInterruptIfRunning == true`. This _should_ bring everything down.

Comment: I ran a quick test and it looks like the request still completes even if `cancel(true)` is called so maybe the task does get interrupted but the request doesn't.

Comment: Looks like you're right. I/O blocking should be interrupted, but only if it's a `java.nio.channels.InterruptibleChannel`. I guess `HttpUriRequest` does not use this.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do a try / catch here - this would only cover the issue and the abort would not be done in this case. You could e.g. spawn a thread to do the abort

Comment: Assuming my theory is correct, by then the request would have completed and there would be no reason to abort it.

Answer (score 0):

try to cancel request before abort

```
@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
{
    TestTask.this.cancel(true);
    if (request != null)
        request.abort(); // this causes NetworkOnMainThreadException sometimes
}
```